# Запрет индексации одного из двух доменов одного сайта

Tags: seo, индексация, robots.txt

Всем привет. У меня есть сайт, который доступен по двум адресам: `mysite.com` и `mysite.some.com`. Оба адреса ведут на один сайт.

Нужно: полностью запретить индексацию сайта для одного из доменов, например для `mysite.com`.

Для каждого домена, формирую свой `robots.txt`. Вот что пишу для домена, который нужно скрыть от индексации (`mysite.com`):

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /

User-Agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
Host: mysite.some.com
```

Но в результатах поиска Google выводится этот запрещенный домен. При том в описании написано:

> Описание веб-страницы недоступно из-за ограничений в файле robots.txt. Подробнее...

Что делать, чтобы полностью запретить индексацию для `mysite.com`?

Comment: Прописал код, как в примере, только для кириллического домена. Сайт не работает. Подскажите, где ошибся: RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^xn--d1abavhdn0a2a\.xn--p1ai RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_tehmedkom-rf.txt [L] Прописал, как во втором примере RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xn--d1abavhdn0a2a\.xn--p1ai [NC] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots\.txt [NC] RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ http://xn--d1abavhdn0a2a.xn--p1ai/robots_tehmedkom-rf.txt [L] Сайт работает, но роботс.txt отдаётся не тот. Или может .htaccess не понимает домены .рф?
P.S. robots.txt отдавался плагином - плагин деактивировал, файл создал.

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы поступил следующим образом...

В файл `.htaccess` добавляем

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ disallow.txt [L]
```

mysite.com понятно заменить на свой)

в корне сайта создать файл `disallow.txt` и записать

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /

User-Agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
Host: mysite.some.com
```

или что там у вас!

В итоге на этих двух сайтах файл robots.txt при запросе в адресной строке, должен быть разный!

Comment: Он у меня разный для двух доменов. На одном (mysite.some.com) разрешается, на другом (mysite.com)полный запрет индексации.

Comment: Так в чем тогда вопрос? Вы думали гугл во мгновение удалит из индекса все страницы в тот момент как вы добавили запрет?

Comment: А сколько должно пройти времени, чтобы домен полностью удалился из поисковиков?

Comment: домен останется в результата поиска Гугла. Нужно еще обязательно в Webmaster Tools удалить * страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Google ожидает [canonical url](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ru/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html): чтобы каждая страница зеркала содержала тег `link` на "правильную" страницу.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.com/page123.html" />
```

Если требуется именно запретить индексацию, когда запрашивается определённый домен, можно подготовить две версии файла robots.txt и выдавать нужную через mod_rewrite правило, в зависимости от `HOST`, что-то типа (не проверял):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^mysite\.site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/robots\.txt [NC]
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$  http://mysite.site.com/robots.mysite.txt [L]
```

Comment: А что если через Вебмастера Google и Яндекс запретить индексацию полностью?

Comment: Чтобы [исключить весь сайт из поиска Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663427), надо сделать две вещи:

 1. прописать запрет в robots.txt;
 2. в настройках Google/webmaster удалить из индекса *